# Horizontal-Pod-Autoscale scale only if CPU load is remain constant for given (5 min) duration

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have a k8s cluster deployed in AWS's EKS. Using Kubernetes 1.14 version

Horizontal-Pod-Autoscale scale only if CPU load is remain constant for given (5 min) duration

As we want to take decision after 4-5 mins if load remain high during that duration.

if load reduces after 3-4 mins then don't scale up, but currently we are not able to find any way for that.

`horizontal-pod-autoscaler-upscale-delay` is deprecated.

So we are looking for parameter by which, we can set CPU usage duration for HPA.

Answer (score 1):

horizontal-pod-autoscaler-upscale-delay is removed. It might still work. You can add it to kube-controller arguments and check

Comment: horizontal-pod-autoscaler-upscale-delay its deprecated so did gonna work in 1.14 version